# Awk: how to print the field separator with your columns (field separator also a regular expression)

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that looks like

```
3 5 t27s60  
4 8 s30s40
2 2 t80t10
6 4 s80t10
```

And I want to produce a file like

```
3 5 t27 s60  
4 8 s30 s40
2 2 t80 t10
6 4 s80 t10
```

So I would specify the field separator as s or t, but I want to keep these characters in the output.

Comment: why not `awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " substr($3,1,2) " " substr($3,3,2)}' file` ? Good luck.

Comment: you can't use 2 separator while one this character appearance in sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick awk one-liner:

```
awk '{gsub(/[st]/," &",$0)}1' input.txt
```

outputs:

```
3 5  t27 s60  
4 8  s30 s40
2 2  t80 t10
6 4  s80 t10
```

Here, we use the special meaning of `&` in the `gsub` command: it stands for the machted expression. Hence, `gsub(/[st]/," &",$0)` prepends a blank before each "s" or "t"

If repeated blanks are a problem:

```
awk '{gsub(/[st]/," &",$0);gsub(/[ ]+/," ",$0)}1' input.txt
```

which gives:

```
3 5 t27 s60 
4 8 s30 s40
2 2 t80 t10
6 4 s80 t10
```

Comment: What is the 1 after the curly braces for

Comment: It makes awk print the current line, as awk interprets 1 as `TRUE`. If nothing else is specified, awk prints the line. That's just a quick way of writing `{print $0}`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it is not possible to obtain the exact field delimiter when `FS` has been set to a regular expresssion.

I would use `sed` for this use case:

```
sed 's/...$/ &/' file
```

The `s` command substitutes the last 3 characters in a line `...` before the end `$` by a space and itself `&`.

---

If counting characters from the end does not work because the number of characters after the delimiter is not fixed, you can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -r 's/(s|t)([^st]+)$/ \1\2/' file
```

I'm searching for `s` or `t` using `(s|t)` followed by 1 or more characters until the which are neither `s` or `t`.

Answer (score 1):

Or perl, add a space before an "s" or "t", if the previous character is not whitespace:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\S)([st])/ $1/g' file
```

The equivalent awk is

```
awk '{print gensub(/([^[:blank:]])([st])/, "\\\1 \\\2", "g")}' file
```